# comparing STL chrono results with floating point

Tags: c++, stl, c++-chrono

I am trying to use the STL chrono library in C++ 11 to measure duration of a loop. So, I am trying to do something as follows:

```
using std::chrono;

double frame_time = 40; // Temporal resolution milliseconds
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
while (get_frame(frame)) {
    // Do something
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);

    // Now I want to do something like:
    if (elapsed < frame_time) { sleep(frame_time-elapsed);}
    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
}
```

However, that comparison results in errors like:

```
 no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘std::chrono::duration<long 
                           int, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >’ and ‘double’)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `frame_time` is also a duration, so why not use `std::chrono::milliseconds`? That way your code becomes cleaner (you wouldn't need your comment for a start) and safer, e.g if `sleep()` was changed to use microseconds the compiler can warn you or select the right overload.

Comment: Sorry got a bit confused. frame_time here is a variable of type double. You mean convert it to duration type?

Comment: no, not convert. Do not use `double` in the first place. Make `frame_time` a variable of type `milliseconds`.

Comment: Ahhhh... I see. I simplified this a bit. The frame_time is actually coming from a third party lib and this returns it as type double. I set it to some hard-coded value to emphasize my problem.

Comment: Then convert, it still makes sense to do the calculation in terms of the domain and let the type system handle unit correctness

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare `chrono::duration` and double. Just use [count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) function of duration object.

```
if (elapsed.count() < frame_time) 
{ 
   sleep(frame_time-elapsed.count());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Did did what I wanted :)

Comment: or better use `std::chrono::milliseconds` instead of double for frame_time

Comment: @FabioFracassi: That should be an alternative answer (and I'd upvote it over this answer)